# Retrieving netmask for interfaces with multiple IP addresses using Python?

Tags: python, linux, networking

I need to list the available network interfaces and their IP addresses and corresponding netmasks using Python in a Linux environment.  I can get the interfaces and the IP addresses of each interface using `ioctl` and `SIOCGIFCONF` as outlined [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/439093-get-names-of-all-up-network-interfaces-linux-only/), but I'm at loss when it comes to determining the netmask when there are multiple IP address on an interface.

I can get the netmask of the primary IP address of an interface as suggested in [Retrieving network mask in Python](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/439093-get-names-of-all-up-network-interfaces-linux-only/):

```
import socket
import fcntl
import struct

SIOCGIFNETMASK = 0x891b

def get_network_mask(ifname):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    netmask = fcntl.ioctl(s, SIOCGIFNETMASK, struct.pack('256s', ifname))[20:24]
    return socket.inet_ntoa(netmask)

>>> get_network_mask('eth0')
'255.255.255.0'
```

However, this won't work if I have multiple IP addresses with different netmasks on the same interface, as follows:

```
$ ip addr show eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.1.1/16 brd 192.168.255.255 scope global eth0
    inet 172.16.0.123/24 scope global eth0
```

In this case I'll only be able to retrieve one of the netmasks using the above function.  Is there a way to retrieve the netmasks for all addresses, except by parsing the output from `ip addr show` or `ifconfig`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically what "ip addr sh" does is use the netlink library to interrogate (and optionally monitor) the kernel network interfaces / routing tables.

You might be able to do this in python, but I strongly recommend parsing the output of "/sbin/ip addr sh"

This is because

- Using the rtnetlink library is complicated
- You don't care about performance - network interfaces don't change often enough that you care (and in any case you can monitor them using "ip monitor")

Comment: Thanks. I had a quick look at rtnetlink, and you're right in that it seems overly complex for this task.  Parsing `ip addr show` still feels a bit hackish, but I guess it's the best way forward in this case.